# Migrating data with south to a new model not working

Tags: django, data-migration, django-south

I have an abstract model that I'm converting to a concrete model. I'm successfully using south to change the schema, but I'm unable to use the datamigration.

My initial state is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, \
                                related_name='profile')
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
class SpecificProfile(UserProfile):
    url = models.URLField()
```

My new state is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, \
                                related_name='profile')
class SpecificProfile(UserProfile):
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, parent_link=True)
    url = models.URLField()
```

My schema migration is:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Renaming field 'SpecProfile.user_profile'
        db.rename_column('specificprofile', 'user_id', 'user_profile_id')

        # Adding model 'UserProfile'
        db.create_table('userprofile', (
            ('user', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField')(related_name='profile', unique=True, primary_key=True, to=orm['auth.User'])),
        ))
        db.send_create_signal('myapp', ['UserProfile'])
```

I edited the file generated by south in order to rename one field in SpecificProfile

Now, in the data migration process, I would like to create one UserProfile entry per `SpecificProfile` and assign `UserProfile.user_id` to `SpecificProfile.user_profile_id`.

So, my data migration forwards is:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        for spec in orm.SpecificProfile.objects.all():
            user_profile = orm.UserProfile()
            user_profile.user_id = spec.user_profile_id
            user_profile.save()
```

The script runs without errors but does not create any new entry in UserProfile table.
Should I use `UserProfile()` instead of `orm.UserProfile()`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`SpecificProfile.user_profile_id` didn't exist previously, so it has no data to migrate. What you really are wanting to do is set `user_profile.user` to `spec.user`, and then set `spec.user_profile` to `user_profile`.

```
 def forwards(self, orm):
    for spec in orm.SpecificProfile.objects.all():
        user_profile = orm.UserProfile()
        user_profile.user_id = spec.user_id
        user_profile.save()

        # Then,
        spec.user_profile_id = user_profile.id
```

However, once you've done the initial migration, I'm pretty sure `SpecificProfile.user` doesn't exist anymore. South removes that field since it's now on `UserProfile`.

Comment: SpecificProfile.user_profile_id should exist after the schemamigration, since I rename SpecificProfile.user_id to SpecificProfile.user_profile_id. Check my schemamigration code above. This renaming is working fine. 
I tested your code, just in case, but it did not work either, probably for the reason you pointed out.

Comment: My problem is that orm.SpecificProfile.objects.all() is returning an empty list